# What is "not serializable" in this custom Groovy script or Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to import script to groovy script using load function in "script" directive. Below is the simplified codes that i'm bring to achieve

Project structure

```
Jenkinsfile
script.groovy
helper/
       Builder.groovy
```

Jenkinsfile

```
....
stage ('Build') {
    steps {
        script {
            def executer = load "script.groovy"
            executer.printText()
        }
    }
}
....
```

script.groovy

```
import helper.Builder

builder = new Builder()

def printText(){
    def text = builder.getText()
    println text
}
```

Builder.groovy

```
package helper

class Builder{
    def getText(){
        return "blah"
    }
}
```

However, when running the Jenkinfile, it keeps failing and I noticed that the code "import helps.builder" causes issue. But I should be able to import Builder class into "script.groovy" so that I can call Builder.getText() function.

One thing that I don't understand is that when I try running script.groovy using terminal, it works well and no issue.

Does anyone have an idea?

By the way, below is the error message from Jenkins

```
an exception which occurred:
     in field collector
     in field abnormal
     in field outcome
     in field body
     in field step
     in field thread
     ....
     ....
 Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
....
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jenkins pipeline groovy sandbox doesn't really behave anything like the command line. it would be possible to debug this, but your mileage is bound to vary depending on the versions of jenkins core and the pipeline plugins you're running. and even when you get it to work, it's likely to break in future versions. you should instead use [jenkins shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), which are the supported way to inject shared code into pipelines.